# cpp linux: about rdtsc

Tags: c++, linux, rdtsc

I'm using the following function in my code:

```
static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void){
  unsigned long long int x;
  __asm__ volatile (".byte 0x0f, 0x31" : "=A" (x));
  return x;
}
```

Does this function return number of ticks since last boot?
Where can I find documentation about this function?

Comment: Did you try the Intel manuals? http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Comment: Also a simple Wikipedia search yields this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Answer (score 1):

`RDTSC` gets the number of cpu cycles since last reset, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter).

the Intel Instruction Set Manual Vol 2A & B, as a more trusted source:

> The processor monotonically increments the time-stamp counter MSR
>   every clock cycle and resets it to 0 whenever the processor is reset.
>   See “Time Stamp Counter” in Chapter 16 of the Intel® 64 and IA-32
>   Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3B, for specific
>   details of the time stamp counter behavior.

as a side note: you shouldn't be emitting bytes, rather use the actual `RTDSC` instruction mnemonic, makes it far more readable.

Comment: I was surprised by the `.byte` way of doing it as well, but it seems lifted from here - http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~kazutomo/rdtsc.html . I wonder why they do it like that?

Comment: @mattjgalloway: I remember older inline assemblers would sometimes require inline byte emission because they didn't recognize the mnemonic, that that was LONG ago, there isn't any advantage other than confusing the reader

Comment: Yeh that would make sense :-).